# MySQL: understanding WHERE clause applying modes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm reading [High Performance MySQL](http://www.amazon.co.uk/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/1449314287/).

**I want to understand:** phrase below

> In general, MySQL can apply a WHERE clause in three ways, from best to
>   worst:
>
> 1. Apply the conditions to the index lookup operation to eliminate non matching rows. This happens at the storage engine layer.
> 2. Use a covering index (“Using index” in the Extra column) to avoid row accesses, and filter out non matching rows after retrieving each
>      result from the index. This happens at the server layer, but it
>      doesn’t require reading rows from the table.
> 3. Retrieve rows from the table, then filter non matching rows (“Using where” in the Extra column). This happens at the server layer and
>      requires the server to read rows from the table before it can filter
>      them.

**My understanding:** Suppose I have

```
table
|-id     <- PK
|-field1 <- 1st B-Tree index
|-field2 <- 2nd B-Tree index
|-field3 <- not indexed
```

- 1st case: `SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE id IN (@id1, @id2, ...)`
- 3rd case: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field3 = 'blabla'`

**Problem:** I don't understand where we get the second case.

***Questions:** *To which cases belongs the next queries?*

1. `SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field1 = 'blabla'`
2. `SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE field1 = 'blabla' AND field2 = 'blabla'`
3. Where we get the second case?

Comment: "Covering index" means that index _can be applied to reduce rows set, but can not be used to eliminate all non-matching rows_. That means - using index will reduce searching row set, but that reduced row set will still be needed to be filtered further. Normally, that occurs when you have multi-column index and your `SELECT` statement uses left-subset of columns from it.

Comment: @AlmaDo For instance `SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE ...`. **Question:** *will MySQL use coverring index when selected field set belongs to two different indexes?*

Comment: You are missing most important part in the query above - `WHERE` part. No matter what fields are you selecting, it won't affect anything. But `WHERE` condition matters. Also, MySQL is able to use _only one index_ for query (but it may be used multiple times). So, if fields in condition are parts of different indexes, by default, MySQL will choose best option (i.e. which reduces row set to minimum).

Comment: @AlmaDo Isn't really it   matter which fields I'm selecting? But if I'll select `field3` which isn't indexed? Than seems MySQL couldn't use *index coverring* because that field isn't held in index.

Comment: you may select anything. Even `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...`. Actual index usage (or not) will be determined by such things as `WHERE` clause

Comment: @AlmaDo why all books about MySQL says that `SELECT *` is evil? I can provide you an reference. Once of the main statements in `Hight Performance MySQL` is **`You should select as few fields possible`**

Comment: because `SELECT *` will result in all fields selection. But __it has nothing to do__ with index usage. It will cause overhead (i.e. performance impact) from another side, which is not related to current topic

Comment: @AlmaDo sorry for abusing, but `SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE ..` can pull all data from index `field1_idx` and have no need to iterate through table at all. Whereas `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...` must to ask table rows in any case, no matter what we pointed in `WHERE` clause. Am I right? Also can you move all your comments into separate answer please?

Comment: What you've written above is wrong. Indexes have nothing to do with fields which you are selecting (you may select anything - expression may contain function calls, operators, e t.c. - how could index know that? It's just makes no sense to mix index usage with that). Also, comments here are about the thing, that you're confusing selection & index usage, so I doubt they are on-topic

Comment: @AlmaDo **`Hight Performance MySQL, 3rd eddition, pg. 203`** `You should always be suspicious when you see SELECT * . Do you really need all columns? Probably not. Retrieving all columns can prevent optimizations such as covering indexes` (c)

Comment: Again: __how is that related to index usage??__ `I give up`

Comment: @AlmaDo sorry, seems you're right. Can you make your answer and provide an example for each of 3 cases of WHERE clause please

Comment: @V_B [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) is your only true friend. :)

Comment: @V_B What is meant there is something like this: `select index_covered_column_but_no_other_column from table` Given this, to select data MySQL doesn't have to access the table, it can return values from the index directly. But this may not be true for multiple columns, even if they are all indexed (with different indexes I mean), cause MySQL uses only one index per table per query (given that MySQL can't use special optimization techniques like index merge in that case).

Comment: @fancyPants thanks. Can you explain me the second case for WHERE clause please?

Answer (score 1):

1st case: PK lookup. Ne explanation needed

Your questions:

1: Index lookup. Mysql will evaluate if the index (in its opinion) is faster than a full table scan and will do so. Can be as fast as case one if the values in the index are distinct (even if not enforced by a unique constraint)

2: MySQL will check which index is (in its opinion) better for the case and use it. MySQL can only use one index per join/where clause. If you had an index on field1 and field2 (i.e. index(filed1,field2)) the it would use that one.